Prove that the set of certain boundary points of a convex set is closed.
Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact convex set and $x \notin C$ be a point. Define $$B \equiv \{c \in C \,|\, [x, c] \cap C = \{c\}\},$$ where $[x, c] \equiv \{t x + (1 - t) c \,|\, t \in [0, 1]\}$ is the line segment between $x$ and $c$. Clearly, $B$ is non-empty and bounded. I guess that $B$ is also closed, but unable to formally prove it when $n \geq 3$. Is my conjecture correct? How to prove it?
Thanks.

Here is a counter-example. Take
$$
C = conv\left(  \{x\in \mathbb R^3: \ x_3=0, \ x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 1\} \cup \{ (1,0,1)^T\} \right)
$$
(which is some kind of cone)
and
$$
x = (1,0,2)^T.
$$
Then $B$ contains the boundary points from
$$
\{x\in \mathbb R^3: \ x_3=0, \ x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 1, \ x_1 \ne 0\} 
$$
but not $c:=(1,0,0)^T$, as $(1,0,1)^T \in [x,c]$.

Beautiful. Thank you!

I have a follow-up question. Let $A = \cup_{\text{direction } p : p \cdot x > \max_{c \in C} p \cdot c} \mathop{\arg\max}_{c \in C} p \cdot c$. It is clear that $A \subset B$, and hence $\overline{A} \subset \overline{B}$. Is the converse also true? I can prove it for $n = 2$, but unable to prove when $n \geq 3$.
